# How to open any file saved in data/data using an intent?

Tags: android

I have files saved in `data/data/package/files/myfolder/.` I try to open them with the following method:

```
public static void openFile(Context context, File url) throws IOException {
    // Create URI
    File file = url;
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.d("pathAttach", uri.toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".zip") || url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-wav");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
        // WAV audio file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
        // JPG file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
    } else if(url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") || url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
        // Video files
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    } else {

        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    }   

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

The method does open the correct application for each type of file, however the application does not show the file why it says it does not exist.

The method calls it to call like this:

```
String pathAttach = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() +
                                File.separator + "myfolder/" +
                                messagesList.get(pos).getContent();
    FileOpenUitl.openFile(context, new File(pathAttach));
```

By console I have printed the value of pathAttach and `uri.toString ()` the values obtained for an image are:

- pathAttach: `/data/data/io.github.myuser.myapp/files/myfolder/6010141d505105c092eaf6d002a868a18b48544592cb304a3f173c30b4ee9892.jpeg`
- uri.toString (): `file: ///data/data/io.github.myuser.myapp/files/myfolder/6010141d505105c092eaf6d002a868a18b48544592cb304a3f173c30b4ee9892.jpeg`

According to me everything is fine, but I do not understand why the applications can not load the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/data/data/package/` is your app's private space, and not readable by other applications.

solutions are:

1. export to somewhere in `Environment::getExternalStorage()` where readable by other applications
2. use `FileProvider` to grant temporary read access to your file.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
File file = new File("this is the file path");

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "this is the mime type of file");
startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```